# log4net: How to store data in DB

Tags: database, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am planning to replace few different logging mechanism with the only 1. Also I would like to store data not in file, but in DB.

For this purpose I am planning to choose log4net. But looking on the documentation I don't see a way to configure it to use DB as logs storage.

Am I missed something? Could you please point me if there is a way to store data in DB using log4net. And how to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a good runthrough here:

[How to store log in database using log4net](http://techboom.xyz/2008/09/15/how-to-store-log-in-database-using-log4net/)

Also the [log4net Config Examples](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) show how to setup the config for most databases.

Answer (score 3):

Check [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html).  It will give you examples of how to set up your config for the database you are accessing.